# How do you handle documents, images(psd), etc in you repository?

Tags: mercurial

This might be a noob question. but I'm really torned between adding documents to my repository, in this case Mercurial.

by documents i meant, files that doesn't really go into your program. like PSD, doc, xls.

what's the best way to handle those files, or how do you handle your documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Largefiles](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/LargefilesExtension) extension that shipped with Mercurial 2.0 (with bugfixes since). It's designed to treat files that are binary and update rarely in a different, more efficient way.

Basically it stores those files without trying to compute diffs between versions, and anybody cloning the repo just gets the versions they need, and not all the history. This leads to faster cloning / pulling, but updates may need a connection to the remote repository to read versions of files into the local cache.

Answer (score 1):

I toss them in my repository. It's nice to track changes of them and see old revisions anyway. I can see old revisions of a design document or see what the previous art was for an asset (maybe a graphic designer removed the alpha channel and he/she wasn't supposed to). Throw it in there. If it doesn't change, it's not taking up any more space with a good source control system than storing it outside of source control.

Comment: do you put it in the same repository as your sources or you use a separate one just for documents?

Comment: It depends. I do some creative writing and I throw that in a seperate repository. If it's art, assets, design documents, etc. for a project I'll put it in the same repo as the code. Maybe /docs/ subdirectory, so it's there when I need it and not filling up my base directory.